Drillbit starts running then not running anymore (Apache Drill)
I'm learning Apache Drill and want to deploy Drill on distributed mode but after I start Drillbit, it started successfully but then it auto stopped
('drillbit.pid file is present but drillbit is not running').
I don't know how to fix it, please help me!




